# How to convert BehaviorSubject<Optional<List<File>>> to Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, behaviorsubject

I have BehaviorSubject in RxJava, but I am not able convert it to Kotlin.

```
public class Test {

private final BehaviorSubject<Optional<List<File>>> fileList = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Optional.absent());

void test() {
        File file = new File("");
        fileList.getValue().get().add(file);
    }

}
```

This is converted BehaviorSubject to Kotlin, but I am not able to ADD object (file) to list.

```
class Test {

private val fileList = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(Optional.absent<List<File>>())

internal fun test() {
    val file = File("")
    fileList.value.get().add(file)
    }

}
```

I have following imports:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin distinguishes between immutable Lists (the default), and MutableLists. Declare a MutableList instead.